# Why are the majority of characters in the Star Wars Galaxy human?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

If the Star Wars Galaxy is so vast, why are the majority of the species human (or at least humanoid) English speaking beings?

Comment: Related: [Why are there humans in the Star Wars Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4073/31394) and [Are the humans in the Star Wars Galaxy really humans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110205/31394) and [Is Galactic Basic the same as English?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/227365/31394)

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MostWritersAreHuman

Comment: They breed like Earth rabbits?

Answer (score 5):

According to the Wookieepedia page about humans in Star Wars:

> Humans were one of the most successful colonial species, having migrated and adapted to dominate a variety of worlds. [...] By the time of the Galactic Civil War, humans were the most populous of the galaxy's intelligent species, and could be encountered nearly anywhere communities of people gathered.
>
> Although humans tended to regard their great adaptiveness as a skill, aliens sometimes reproached them for spreading all across the galaxy, forcing themselves upon ecosystems they did not belong to. Burta, a Krish female, notably held that point of view, which she vehemently defended against Jyn Erso.
>
> *"Some people would consider this a skill. Humans adapt. Got mountains? Build ridgecrawlers. Too much water? Build scub-subs. An ice planet? Use radiated igurts. People adapt."*
>
> *"Yes, but should they? Either humans adapt, or they force the planet to adapt to them. This is not normal."*
>
> [Human](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Human), Wookieepedia

As for the [humanoids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Humanoid/Legends) species, a distinction needs to be made between them and the [Near-Humans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Near-Human).

The latter were once humans that evolved into a different direction from the normal humans with minor changes such as skin color, eye color. Those differences in evolution depend mainly on external factors such as the environment of the planets that were colonized.

What's more, these Near-Humans are still genetically close enough to produce an offspring with a normal human.

Humanoids on the other hand, are simply alien beings that are not in any way related to Humans and only meet a few criteria:

- A head on top of the body
- 2 legs
- 2 arms

As for the English language, it is called the [Galactic Basic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Basic_Standard) in the Star Wars universe and it was created by the Republic as a language to be used by most of the species across the galaxy to facilitate trades and politics.

So it's no surprise for the humans and most of the humanoid species to speak it.

Comment: That's all intriguing and no doubt truthful. You've the facts. But sadly on the far-side of the spectrum, many will probably say, all this is only because it's all fantasy made by an English speaking human, for human audiences. But of course not all English speaking audiences, foreign countries have also enjoyed the Star Wars Universes.

Comment: When watching SW you should treat most characters however you like. I don't necessarily attribute every actor that looks human to the human species. Same for the english language, it is used to convey the story to the viewers but I imagine they are speaking an alien language in the movies. Try to abstract the whole context (that is made by humans for humans using humans) and let your imagination work. That is how I tend to watch them.

Comment: Good answer, although kind of weird to attribute the prevalence of humans to our adaptability, when the things that mostly make us adaptable apply equally to any number of other races we've seen in the SW universe. Of course, SW also seems to be a universe of oddly mono-biome planets, so perhaps most species gained space level technology without having to adapt to their environments (or adapt their environment to them) all that much.